# disable a cell based on another cell value in a row in aspxgridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

My Code:

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DataColumn.FieldName == "col7name")
    {
        // Here I can disable the same cell by the following code:
        if ( < condition > )
        {
            e.Cell.Enabled = false;
        }
        // But my question is that how to disable another cell in the same row.
    }
}
```

How to disable another cell in the same row based on another cell value in devexpress aspxgridview?

Comment: Maybe you can use `e.VisibleIndex` to get the whole row?

Comment: `e.VisibleIndex` only returns the integer value that is the column index value

Comment: Not what the documentation says: [Gets the row's visible index. (Inherited from ASPxGridViewRowEventArgs)](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgsMembersTopicAll). You use `e.DataColumn.Index` to get the column index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `e.GetValue("fieldname")` and acheived my goal.